# Why does a object claim to be undefined only when I try to acces one of its properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With the following code:

```
req.Course.find({}).populate('students', 'username firstName lastName registered').populate('teacher', 'image mID firstName lastName').sort({title: 1}).exec(function(err, courses){
    if(err) throw err;
    req.toJade.courses = [];
    if (courses){
        req.toJade.courses = advs;
    }
    res.render('courses/list', req.toJade);
```

});

`courses` is an array of objects in the following format:

```
[{
  _id: objectid,
  title: 'History',
  teacher:
   {
     _id: objectid,
     name: 'John Smith',
     etc...   
   },
   etc...
},
etc...
]
```

I loop through the array of those objects in Jade with and when I try to access a **property** of any teacher with

```
for c in courses:
    h1= c.title
        small= c.teacher.name
```

it returns an error that it cannot read property 'name' of undefined. And this occurs when I try to access any other property of the course object.

However, using

```
for c in courses:
    h1= c.title
        small= c.teacher
```

prints out the whole clearly defined object with the all of its properties existing and with the correct values.

What am I doing wrong and how can I access any of the properties of the teacher objects?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Any chance "teacher" is a "JSON string" instead of an object?

Comment: @MarvinSmit using typeof course.teacher returns object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java script will check for the existence of properties for a particular object only when we access it. Because it is not typed language as C#,Java. In java script we can add or remove properties dynamically.

To check for the existence of a property in an object we can use the function which is available for all the objects in javascript.
**objectname.hasOwnProperty("propertyToCheck")**

Answer (score 2):

`for..in` iterates over all properties of an object. In the case of Arrays, this means all of its values, all of the properties set on the array itself and all of the properties set on `Array.prototype`. Usually when dealing with Arrays you are only interested in the values, so `for..in` is not the best choice.

The proper way to iterate over Array values is by using a a simple `for/while/do while` or by using `Array#forEach` and other similar functional iteration methods:

```
for (var i=0; i<courses.length; i++) {
  var c = courses[i];
  h1 = c.title;
  small = c.teacher.name;
}
// or
courses.forEach(function(c){
  h1 = c.title;
  small = c.teacher.name;
});
```

---

Also, a simple wayto avoid the error if the teacher property is not set would be:

```
small = c.teacher && c.teacher.name;
```

If `c.teacher` is `undefined`, `small` will be `undefined` as well, otherwise it will be equal to `c.teacher.name`.

Adding a default value is just as easy:

```
small = c.teacher && c.teacher.name || 'Unknown teacher';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found my dumb mistake. I wasn't expecting 2 objects in the courses array to have their teacher as undefined. I guess that broke the whole thing since I never checked to see if the teacher property exists.